# Beego Admin Task page not working

Tags: go, beego

In Beego admin Tasks page to make the Task Spec appear and Run button to work? Run button doesn't seem to work and just links to `http://localhost:8888/task?taskname=` without any task name.

Is there a reason why? Below is my code for Task:

```
tk1 := toolbox.NewTask("task1", "0/10 * * * * * ", func() error {
    fmt.Printf("task1 task ran at: %s\n", time.Now())
    return nil
})

toolbox.AddTask("task1", tk1)
toolbox.StartTask()
defer toolbox.StopTask()
```

Comment: Is this line `defer toolbox.StopTask()` called in the main function or init function. If it's not in the main function, delete this line and try.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a synchronization issue (no wait/delay after the `AddTask`/`StartTask` steps).
Try and see if defining several Tasks the way they are defined in [`toolbox/task_test.go`](https://github.com/astaxie/beego/blob/a144769515b8ddfb69046b3ef9e29c38bab94f3b/toolbox/task_test.go) would work better:

```
func TestSpec(t *testing.T) {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(2)
    tk1 := NewTask("tk1", "0 12 * * * *", func() error { fmt.Println("tk1"); return nil })
    tk2 := NewTask("tk2", "0,10,20 * * * * *", func() error { fmt.Println("tk2"); wg.Done(); return nil })
    tk3 := NewTask("tk3", "0 10 * * * *", func() error { fmt.Println("tk3"); wg.Done(); return nil })

    AddTask("tk1", tk1)
    AddTask("tk2", tk2)
    AddTask("tk3", tk3)
    StartTask()
    defer StopTask()

    select {
    case <-time.After(200 * time.Second):
        t.FailNow()
    case <-wait(wg):
    }
}

func wait(wg *sync.WaitGroup) chan bool {
    ch := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        ch <- true
    }()
    return ch
}
```

Comment: I tried this in the task but now when I do bee run the app wouldn't run completely stopping in the middle. I'm calling this task func from my main.go init function